# Convert String error response to Http Status code

Tags: java, spring, httpclient

In Java+Spring application I am using, from a third party called over `RestTemplate` , we get the error response in the JSON with 200 response code.

e.g

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "reason": "did not like the request",
        "error": "BAD_REQUEST"
    }]
}
```

How can I convert `BAD_REQUEST` to the 400 integer representations.
Apache `HttpStatus` inte does not seem to provide any interface to do so.

Comment: So your server replies with an HTTP status of 200 with that content?

Comment: Yes, its other party server response so i cannot change it.

Comment: Ask them all their possible errors, and create your own mapping to standard status codes.

Comment: @JBNizet there is no library to convert string response text to int?

Comment: I think the following URL may be applicable (might not be though, let me know)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401909/spring-resttemplate-post-response

Comment: How would such a library know which strings the third-party chose, and which status code they should be mapped to? These strings are not standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you can use `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`:

```
String error = "BAD_REQUEST";
HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(error);
int errorIntCode = httpStatus.value();
```

or more safe:

```
String error = "BAD_REQUEST";
HttpStatus httpStatus = Arrays.stream(HttpStatus.values())
        .filter(status -> status.name().equals(error))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
int errorIntCode = httpStatus.value();
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

More succinct and short

```
HttpStatus.OK.value();
```