# Spring Rest Client Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring, rest, rest-client

I am using spring `RestTemplate` to consume rest services(exposed in spring rest). I am able to consume success scenarios. But for negative scenarios, service returns error messages and error codes. I need to show those error messages in my web page.

For e.g. for invalid request, service throws `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` with proper messages. If i put try-catch block it goes to catch block and I am not able to get `ResponseEntity` object.

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<MyEntity>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<MyEntity>>() {
    });
    responseEntity.getStatusCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO How to get response here, so that i can get error messages?
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How to get `ResponseWrapper` for exception case?

I read about `CustomRestTemplate` and `ResponseExtractor` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322381/spring-resttemplate-behavior-when-handling-responses-with-a-status-of-no-content) but could not decide which one is best for my case.

Comment: you can create new Response Entity object itself.  new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
for getting error messages , you need to catch RestClientException and get message by rce.getMessage() something like that.

Comment: You can catch HttpStatusCodeException that has the status code http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpStatusCodeException.html

Comment: You can visit bellow thread. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found solution. `HttpClientErrorException` worked for me.

It has `e.getResponseBodyAsString()` function which returns ResponseBody.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to distinguish between:

`HttpClientErrorException` (HTTP-Status >=400) or `HttpServerErrorException` (HTTP-Status >= 500) or even `RestClientException`.

Further on there is a good doc about defining your own ErrorHandler, [see this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.0.5/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java)