# How does Springs RestTemplate handle error responses in postForEntity()

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I have a Spring service calling a Spring Rest endpoint with `RestTemplate.postForEntity`. I can step through the Rest controller and see that it creates and returns a `ResponseEntity` with Status Code 500 -Internal Server Error which is expected in my use case. However the calling spring Service is throwing a `RestClientException` rather than receiving the `ResponseEntity` with status code.

Does `RestTemplate.postForEntity` throw a `RestClientException` when receiving an `ResponseEntity` with a status code that isn't a 2xx?

Comment: I've left out my code in an attempt to keep the question and answers succinct and generalized, but will post if helpful.

Comment: You should definitely post your code.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter ... RestClientException has to be thrown as because it's a 500 error the RestTemplate can't create the body of the required type for you so it throws an exception :)

Comment: This question clears it up a bit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710945/spring-rest-client-exception-handling

Comment: You can visit bellow thread. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945